# How do scrape or download pdfs from a collection of shtml links?

Tags: python, r, pdf, web, screen-scraping

I scraped a list of shtml links. They are now saved in a .xlsx file.

[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYN3z.png)

I already tried looking for excel macros, r code, python code, chrome extensions and desktop programs. I could not find any research that was helpful to me.

Each .shtml link leads to a web page with at least one .pdf at the center of the page that I need to download.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The basic workflow is:

1. you need to use `css` or `xpath` to locate the pdf download button.
2. Use `Rselenium to simulate the download action`; or get the `href` attribute and use `rvest` to make a request to that link, and write the binary response to disk using `writeBin()`

To download a pdf file, I'll use a government form as the example:

pdf url:  https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-765.pdf

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)

session <- html_session("https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-765.pdf")

# save pdf to test.pdf
writeBin(session$response$content,"test.pdf")
```

Comment: Dear Yifu, thanks for your answer!

the href link opens the pdf in a new tab (where the download button is in the top right hands side corner). I am not sure how to code r so that it clicks that button and how to refer to my excel sheet. Do you know where I can find more detailed documentation or could you elaborate more?

Comment: I updated my answer. It should answer your question.

Comment: I can' t know what is happening unless you provide your sample codes. If it's a different issue, please ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

that is helpful!

```
install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("httr")
install.packages("readxl")
update.packages("tibble")

library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(readxl)

setwd("C:/Users/Andreas/Desktop/481064 A.F. - Master Thesis - Election Outcome Prediction/Full Repository Austrian Bundestag")
my_data <- read_excel("StenographischeProto.xlsx")
View(my_data)

session <- html_session("https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-765.pdf")

# save pdf to test.pdf
writeBin(session$response$content,"test.pdf")
```

Comment: this is my code. I am not sure how to extract the href/pdf from each link in the .xslx list. Do you have an idea on how I can go about it?